# How can I ignore a certain value when sorting so it always appears at the bottom of the sorted list

Tags: java

I have a list of items, each item has a price field. some items have price equal to 999. When sorting, I want the elements that have price == 999 to always be at the bottom of the list, whether the sort direction is ascending or descending.

I have tired the the code below and it works for sorting low to high (ascending) but not when descending.

```
Collections.sort(itemList, new Comparator<Item>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Item o1, Item o2) {
        if(sort == 4){ // Low to High
            return Double.compare(o1.getPrice(), o2.getPrice());
        }else{ // High to Low
            return Double.compare(o2.getPrice(), o1.getPrice());

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: An alternative would be to remove the `999` items from the list before sorting and put them back into the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For ascending order:

```
Collections.sort(items, new Comparator<Item>()
{
    @Override
    public int compare(Item o1, Item o2)
    {
        if (o1.getPrice() == 999 && o1.getPrice() < o2.getPrice()) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (o2.getPrice() == 999) {
            return -1;
        }
        return Double.compare(o1.getPrice(), o2.getPrice());
    }
});
```

And for descending order:

```
Collections.sort(items, Collections.reverseOrder(new Comparator<Item>()
{
    @Override
    public int compare(Item o1, Item o2)
    {
        if (o1.getPrice() == 999 || o2.getPrice() == 999) {
            return 1;
        }
        return Double.compare(o1.getPrice(), o2.getPrice());
    }
}));
```

**Test:**

```
List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
items.add(new Item(10));
items.add(new Item(50));
items.add(new Item(1050));
items.add(new Item(999));
items.add(new Item(40));
items.add(new Item(999));
items.add(new Item(30));
items.add(new Item(1050));
```

**Output:**

*Ascending*

```
10.0
30.0
40.0
50.0
1050.0
1050.0
999.0
999.0
```

*Descending*

```
1050.0
1050.0
50.0
40.0
30.0
10.0
999.0
999.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your `compare()` to recognize 999 as a special case which is treated as greater than (if  sorting low to high) or less than (if sorting high to low) any other value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this comparator:

```
Collections.sort(itemList, new Comparator<Item>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Item o1, Item o2) {

        if (o1.getPrice() == 999)
            return -1;
        else if (o2.getPrice() == 999)
            return 1;

        if (sort == 4) { // Low to High
            return Double.compare(o1.getPrice(), o2.getPrice());
        } else { // High to Low
            return Double.compare(o2.getPrice(), o1.getPrice());
        }
    }
});
```